# Most efficient string search method

Tags: string, search

Say I have millions of lines of unique strings spread across hundreds of text files (the "dataset").  Now I want to check to see if any of those text files contain any of 2 million unique strings that are listed in another text file ("tofind").  What would be the most efficient way to go about this?  Some extra application-specific info:

- must be case sensitive
- the string to find would match the found string in full (ie, it is NOT a substring)
- each text file in the "dataset" contains approx 700K lines and is 50MB, though some can be several hundred MB.
- again, the strings in both the "dataset" and "tofind" are unique.  Indexing won't help.
- There is no need to be able to search live (ie, as someone starts typing).  I just want to output any matches to a text file with the match and the the file it was found in.
- I have 32GB of RAM and an i7 3930K

My options include using simple command line/batch "findstr", etc, or possibly writing a search program in vbscript or c# (Java or Python if necessary, but I'm not as familiar with them).  What would be the most efficient solution for this particular application?

Comment: It is not entirely clear whether this is about algorithms for (low-level) string-matching, or about possible data structures, or about (high-level) technologies (e.g. databases). Ideas from the tip of one's head (e.g. "Compute a hash value for each string in each text file of the "dataset", and check whether the hash value of a "tofind" string is contained in the respective set of hash values before actually scanning the file") might either be too obvious or not applicable depending on the exact constraints that are imposed by the surrounding infrastructure....

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory to load all the strings from tofind into memory, then you could create a set of pairs, the key being the length of the strings and the value being the set of strings. Load all your strings from tofind into this structure by storing them based on their length: A string of 5 characters would be stored in the value of the pair having 5 as key, a string of 10 characters would be stored in the value of the pair having 10 as key (you can refine this even more using the same style of grouping with the first character, but I won't describe this here, as I want to share the idea in the simplest possible way).

Then you can load the other strings and search for their occurrences. A string having a length of 10 would be searched in your pair having 10 as key, for instance.

If the size of the data set is just too large, then you can do the same by loading a batch of strings at a time and then purge the structure and rebuild it with the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have to do this in real time it gives you a lot of lattitude in
designing a search process. I have not thought this through very carefully but it seems to
me that you could do this in a couple of steps:

**Step 1**

Eliminate those strings from the *dataset* that you know do not match any of the strings
in the *tofind* string list. A [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) is a very effective way to accomplish this.
It has a zero false negative rate, that is, if there isn't a hit on the bloom filter
then none of the strings match and the string can be eliminated.

The strings that hit on the Bloom Filter then need to be verified to ensure you did not
get a false positive. Bloom Filters are prone to false positives. However if you pay
close attentention to selecting good hashing functions and allocate a large enough filter, the
false positive rate can be quite low.

For each string where there is a hit on the Bloom Filter, save that string and the position in
the string where the hit was made. This information is passsed to Step 2.

**Step 2**

Verify strings that hit on the Bloom Filter. Now you need to verify all 1M *tofind* strings
using an efficient exact string matching function. A [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) seems like a good candidate for this
function. Load the *tofind* strings into the Trie and then search it starting at the position
found by the Bloom Filter. At this point you will either have a hit, in which case
a match was found, or a miss in which case the Bloom Filter reported a false positive.

**Note:** This process assumes that Step 1 can eliminate a significant number of strings from
the *dataset*. If you expect that most *dataset* strings will contain a match in **tofind** then
it might not be worth the effort.